Power Automate 'when an item is created, or modified in a library' - to know exact changes
Situation: I created an Automate flow on cloud, triggered by "when an item is created, or modified in a library". The trigger works, i.e. the flow starts when I change something in the lib. But I don't know how to get the exact changes, example: value of a column, or new file added, ...
Question: How to get the exact changes, to set suitable action?
FYI: ChatGPT says this is not possible. But you guys may be better than AI :)

ChatGPT is right.

As of now, it is not very straightforward.
Firstly, to determine whether the item was created or modified you can use such condition:
equals(triggerOutputs()?['body/Created'], triggerOutputs()?['body/Modified'])

if true - then the item was created, otherwise - modified.
Secondly, to understand what specifically was modified you can call use the action "Get changes for an item or a file (properties only)":
Example
Example parameters are:
Id:    triggerOutputs()?['body/ID']
Since: sub(int(triggerOutputs()?['body/{VersionNumber}']),1)
Until: triggerOutputs()?['body/{VersionNumber}']
Include Minor Versions: No

Then, operate conditions like:
outputs('Get_changes_for_an_item_or_a_file_(properties_only)')?['body/ColumnHasChanged/Project']

to understand if it is true or not.
In the end, if you need an old value from a previous version - you can use such actions: Example

If you find my answer useful - please vote for it or mark as "Accepted".
